# Angular material layout pushing footer out of window

Tags: html, css, angularjs, layout, angular-material

I'm stuck on a problem with using the Angular Material JS and CSS. I'm having problems getting the `<main>` tag to take up the available height without pushing my footer below the bottom of the window. I've been banging my head against this for 2 days now, and I know it's got to be something simple that I'm missing between all of the flex-ing and layout-fills.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/snydercreative/pen/KdBzXp

Answer (score 2):

It's something I've been struggling with too. Turns out for flex to expand properly it has to be inside of a layout. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjZROp

Here's the key parts:

```
<div class="wrapper" layout-fill layout="column">
```

and

```
<main flex>
```

As long as main is the only `flex` element inside its parent layout, it will grow to the proper height.

Here's a simplified version to hopefully make it a bit clearer: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mejRze